# Reading files from S3 bucket with camel

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-aws

I am new to Camel and need some guidance. I need to read some files from an S3 bucket. The structure is like so.

````
S3 Bucket 
```
Incoming  
    +xls    
           -file1.xls  
           -file2.xls  
           -file3.xls   
    +doc  
           -file1.doc  
           -file2.doc  
           -file3.doc 

Processed
    +xls
    ...
    +doc
    ...
````

When a particular excel file is dropped into the incoming/xls folder (say file1.xls), I need to pick up all the files, do some processing and drop them into a processed folder with the same directory structure.

What components do I need to use for this? I tried reading the documentation but its a little difficult to figure out what components I need. I understand that I will use the camel-aws-s3 plugin but there are not many examples of it out there.

Answer (score -1):

On the https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws-s3-component.html there some examples about writing and reading from a S3 Bucket.
Next to reading and writing to S3, you might need some custom processor that uses Apache POI to transform the xsl files

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but providing links that are broken is not the best option to help others. Also, if you can provide actual code that solves the issue is preferable than giving hints on what to do.